# Swift 3: Getting a return segue to play a sound effect

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'll get straight to the point as i feel my title may need to be addressed further to truly understand my predicament. Essentially; i have two view controllers linked up with a modal segue; with the initial working portion of my first View's primary function looking like this:

```
 @IBAction func beginButton(_ sender: Any) {
        audioPlayer.play()
            }
```

The second view controller is set up as follows; which functions perfectly excluding the desirability to play the same audioPlayer

```
 func performSegueToReturnBack()  {
         audioPlayer.play()
            if let nav = self.navigationController {

                nav.popViewController(animated: true)
            } else {

                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

    }
```

Any ideas on how to get this working would be much appreciated; thanks for any help!

Comment: What you want to do exactly ?

Comment: All i want is the performSegueToReturnBack function to be able to successfully play the audioPlayer; but no sound is produced when the function is called

Comment: Try it out - `override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        audioPlayer.play()
    }`

Comment: Thanks Jack, resolved my issue perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may be missing some code. This is how would accomplish what you are attempting to do.

```
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    let alertSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "CheckoutScannerBeep", ofType: "mp3")!) // If sound is not in an asset
    //let alertSound = NSDataAsset(name: "CheckoutScannerBeep") // If sound is in an Asset

func testSound(){
    do {
        //        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: (alertSound!.data), fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3) //If in asset
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: alertSound) //If not in asset
        audioPlayer.pan = -1.0 //left headphone
        //audioPlayer.pan = 1.0 // right headphone
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.volume = 50
        audioPlayer.play()
    } catch  {
        print("error")
    }

}

func performSegueToReturnBack()  {
     testSound()
        if let nav = self.navigationController {

            nav.popViewController(animated: true)
        } else {

            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

}
```